How to show $\int_0^{\pi/2} \text{arcsinh}(\sin x) dx =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$?
I'd like to show that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \text{arcsinh}(\sin x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}.$$
I tried to proceed as follows:

I showed that
$$ \text{arcsinh }x = \ln\left( x + \sqrt{x^2+1} \right). $$
I know that Taylor polynomial of arcsinh $x$ centered in $x=0$ is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} (1/2)_n $$
where $(x)_n$ denote the falling factorial.

I have a problem to show the second point.
Could someone help me, please!
P. S.: Merry Christmas to everyone
First edit: I'd like to know why Taylor polynomial of arcsinh $x$ centered in $x=0$ is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}}\dbinom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
Second edit: I'd like to know why
$$ \binom{-1/2}{n} = (-1/4)^n \binom{2n}{n}.$$
My apologies if my question was not so clear.
Last comment: Using Legendre duplication formula. I solved my problem. Thank you for answers.

See this one.

This doesn't answer my question because I don't know the proof to the fact that Taylor polynomial of arcsinh x is that described in the link you send me

Anyway, thx for answer

The series (asked for, as a missing step in this answer)
$$
\operatorname{arcsinh}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1},\quad a_n\color{gray}{=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(1/2)_n}=\binom{-1/2}{n}\color{gray}{=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}}
$$
is obtained by integrating $(\operatorname{arcsinh}x)'=(1+x^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{2n}$ (binomial series).

Thx, I know this formula, but not the proof of $$\binom{-1/2}{n}=(-1/2)^n\binom{2n}{n}.$$ I'd like to know this. Thx again and excuse me if my question was not so clear.

@Puck Just manipulate the definition: $$\binom{-1/2}{n}
= \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(-\tfrac{1}{2} - k \right)
= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k + 1)
\= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n} n!^2} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k + 2)(2k + 1)
= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n} n!^2} (2n)!
= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n}.$$
